How to std::accumulate chars in a string as digits using lambda?
How can I sum all digits in a string num into an integer sum using a lambda?
std::string num = "1234567891011";

int sum = accumulate(num.begin(), num.end(), 0, [](auto & a, auto & b)
{
    // ???
    // return int(a - '0') + int(b - '0') causes an error
});

With this num, sum must be equal 48.

Personally, I would use int sum = 0; for (auto ch : num) sum += ch - '0';

Re: "causes an error" -- what does the error message say?

Don't address it to me. Add it to your question.

Ahhhh, auto. Such a blessing. Except when it is a curse.

Side note: even if a is a char, the type of a - '0' is int. The compiler promotes smaller types to int or unsigned int to do arithmetic. There's no need for those casts.

Assuming that the num will always have chars between 0 and 9, you can accumulate as follows:
int sum = std::accumulate(num.begin(), num.end(), 0, [](int a, char b) {
        return a + (b - '0');
});

